# Select query not working on external table

Tags: hadoop2, greenplum, hawq

We have a small array of Greenplum cluster. In that we installed Hadoop. and trying to access external table using GPHDFS protocol.

**ENV**

- GPDB VERSION 4.3.10
- HDP VERSION 2.3.6
- JAVA VERSION 1.8  acroos master /segments

**Getting error**

```
prod=# select count (*) from schemaname.filename;
ERROR: external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again (seg1 slice1 datanaodehostname:40001 pid=8221)
DETAIL:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMain
Command: 'gphdfs://hadoop/file/path?profile=HdfsTextSimple'
External table ext_tableneme, file gphdfs://hadoop/file/path?profile=HdfsTextSimple
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Comment: gphdfs doesn't have syntax like "profile=HdfsTextSimple" in pxf. Refer to gphdfs doc in Pivotal

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake i  appended  hawq pxf profile here, I REMOVED AND tried with removing  profile=HdfsTextSimple. it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in psql, run "show gp_hadoop_home"
You should see it points to your HDP home.
If not, use  gpconfig -c gp_hadoop_home -v "'/usr/hdp/current"  to reset the hadoop home in gpdb.